# GoogleVisualr How to Set its Axis format to N significant figures

Tags: google-visualization

I'm referring to this page

[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes)
And find that I can format my axis to following pattern:

{format: 'none'}: displays numbers with no formatting (e.g., 8000000)

{format: 'decimal'}: displays numbers with thousands separators (e.g., 8,000,000)

{format: 'scientific'}: displays numbers in scientific notation (e.g., 8e6)

{format: 'currency'}: displays numbers in the local currency (e.g., $8,000,000.00)

{format: 'percent'}: displays numbers as percentages (e.g., 800,000,000%)

{format: 'short'}: displays abbreviated numbers (e.g., 8M)

{format: 'long'}: displays numbers as full words (e.g., 8 million)

Can I format the axis to 4 significant figures?

say 0.000002345786 the axis display 0.000002346
and 0.0234567 display 0.02346

Is there a setting to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '@@@@'});
```

I haven't actually tested it, but the Google Visualization Docs linked [this page](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#sigdig) which suggests this pattern should format to 4 significant digits.

Comment: Not technically part of my answer, but [significant figures](http://bit.ly/significantdigits) are a very complex problem, not necessarily represented well by the number value alone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be easier if you format the numbers in Ruby instead before passing them to GoogleVisualr.

This is actually the main motivation of GoogleVisualr, because it allows you to do manipulation of the data in Ruby, which should be simpler.